# Spring WebFlux + thymeleaf: Post request redirect Get page returns the 303 see other status

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

I just used SpringBoot + WebFlux + thymeleaf to write the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createCityForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("city", new City());
    model.addAttribute("action", "create");
    return CITY_FORM_PATH_NAME;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postCity(@ModelAttribute City city) {
    cityService.saveCity(city);
    return REDIRECT_TO_CITY_URL;
}
```

I witre thymeleaf page to receive the form, and redirect/return the get method page, But the browser give the 303 see other status.
Also, the delete resources also doesn't work.

Comment: You need to provide more detail than this. Add your VIewresolver code. property file if you are using .  seems like redirect is not configured properly

Answer (score 0):

The `SEE_OTHER` status is actually the default status of the `RedirectView` when invoked without explicitly specifying the HTTP code (like the `ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver` does).

If you want to override this status, return the `RedirectView` directly instead of letting Thymeleaf do it when it matches the `redirect:` pattern in the view name:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView createCityForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("city", new City());
    model.addAttribute("action", "create");
    return new RedirectView("/target_url", HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
}
```